# Cannot access router connected as switch

Tags: networking, router

I have an issue with my network configuration. I have a home network setup `WAN -> Router -> Switch -> PC` but instead of a switch I used a router due to lack of proper equipment available :D.  Of course I disabled DHCP and it works just fine but I realized that I left unprotected Wi-fi available. The problem is that I can't connect to that Switch/Router's settings. I could just reset the router to defaults but there are lots of other settings that I would not like to lose. Is there a way to connect to it through some different gateway or otherwise?

EDIT: 
arp -a shows some IP's but I can connect only to one of them and that is the WAN router. Unfortunately I can't login to WAN router because it was setup by my internet provider and I don't know the password

Comment: In case anyone else sees this, some routers (not sure if while in switching only mode though) are accessed through a domain name like routerlogin.net/com for some Netgear devices instead of their IP

Answer (score 1):

Old post but I just spent hours trying to solve this and this worked for me.

When setting up the old router as a switch/access point, set its LAN IP to exactly what the default gateway of the router is, except change the last number. For example if my routers default gateway is 192.168.0.1 set the switches IP to 192.168.0.2 **before** disabling DHCP.

For people who have **already disabled DHCP** and now can't log back into the "router turned switch" like me you'll need to do this (windows):

Note: my switches IP was 192.168.1.2 which is why I needed to do the following step to log back in. Notice the only difference is the 1 in the IP. That's the problem.

1. Go into your computers **Local Area Connection Properties**
2. Double click **Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)**
3. Select "**Use the following IP address:**"
4. Set the IP address to exactly what the switches IP is (192.168.1.2 in my example), **but change the last number** to something else e.g. 192.168.1.22
5. Press Tab to automatically fill in the Subnet Mask and click OK.
6. Now in the browser go the the **switches** IP address (192.168.1.2).

You should now be prompted to login like you're used to. Just remember to change the IP of the "router turned switch" to the same as the routers default gateway (mentioned above), then undo the changes to the IPv4 settings you just made to your computer.

See [here](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/174/#:%7E:text=Open%20the%20web%20browser%20and,bar%20and%20then%20Press%20Enter.) for more on that last part.

IPv4 settings:

[image: IPv4 settings img]

Answer (score 0):

Your current gateway is the IP address of the router that is connected to the WAN.

You can easily connect to the router-as-a-switch's control panel - you just need to find its IP address.

You can do that with arp, both on Windows and Linux:

```
arp -a
```

This will list you all machine's IP addresses from your local network that are currently connected (if there is discovery).

Another way would be to open the control panel of your router connected to WAN and from a status page try to find which IP addresses are connected to the router. Or if you have SSH access to that router - use the arp command there.

Comment: `arp -a` shows a bunch of IP's but I can't connect with any of them except for the WAN router and accessing the control panel of a router connected to WAN is impossible as that router was setup by my internet provider and I don't know the password. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Connect to the unprotected Wifi.

Then run an `ipconfig` and look for the default gateway on your wireless network adapter.

That's the IP of the router.  Then open a browser and go to `http://192.168.XXX.XXX`, substituting that default gateway for `192.168.XXX.XXX`.

You may try `https://192.168.XXX.XXX` or `http://192.168.XXX.XXX:8000` if the first one doesn't work.

Common router IPs are:

192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.254, 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.254, 192.168.1.50, 192.168.1.100.

Set your computer's IP to 192.168.0.253, subnet mask to 255.255.255.0, and try all of those in a browser.